# Installing the package php-cli 8.0.1 from the official remote repo?

Tags: apt, package-management, php, snap

Is it possible to install `php-cli` for PHP 8.0.1 from the official remote repository, without having to modify my repo list `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`?

Comment: For which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

You need to download the dependencies `php8.0-common`,`php8.0-opcache`, `php8.0-readline` and `php-cli` from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/) then install them through `dpkg`.

But installing the packages through `apt` is more preferred after adding the ppa , next time it can be removed through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
```

**NB**: The installed packages will not receive any updates including the security updates. It is better to keep the ppa.